# How much hard drive space should I allocate to Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive

I am setting up VirtualBox and I am allocating 4 GB RAM (on my 16 GB Windows machine) to Ubuntu. However, I also need to choose a hard drive size.

I'm not sure what to choose. I want to experiment with LAMP servers, do some coding/scripting, etc, but I don't know a reasonable amount to allocate. 8 GB seems to be too limiting, but is 25 GB too much?

I have ~250 GB hard drive space left on my hard drive, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the disk to dynamic and choose about 100GB, then the drive will grow as you need it to but not larger then 100GB and it will stay small and only expand as you add more applications.

For example if your install size is 10GB then that will be the actual size of the disk but it will be able to grow as needed up to 100GB or whatever you set the limit at.

Dynamic hard drive space is explained in the last image.
[image: Disk] [image: VDI][image: Dynamic]

Comment: Is there any reason NOT to choose a large number? I guess the max cap just exists so the host machine suddenly doesn't get squeezed over time?

Comment: No reason at all I usually go with about 180GB myself. You can not grow it larger then the disk drive size is, I set my this large and I usually never go over about 20GB but it is nice to have the option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default value is set at 20GB. But if you are only going to set up a LAMP stack and do some coding you don't really need that much space. I would go for 10-15GB. Which is alot more then you probably need.