# Is this a good idea on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

So I have a basic understanding of Hypervisors and have decided I should start making use of them.

I'm planning on doing the following:

Ubuntu (Base System)

=====Virtual Box======

Arch + Kali + OSX + Win7

I have the RAM and Disk for this but is it a good idea?

My aim is to basically make my laptop an IT pocket knife that I can whip out and fix anything with.

What is recommended for creating partitions and what size should they be?

Cheers

Comment: So what is your problem? I don't see a problem?

Comment: Was looking for advice more then a solution

Comment: Hi lemur, can you please change your question so it is easier to know what you are asking. Right now am only seeing what you have, not what you want.

Comment: Hopefully the edit helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have about 20 virtual machines so yes I believe it is a good idea. You do not have to run them all at once.

I use mine to diagnose wireless issues and test compiz and its settings.

I usually only run about three at a time.

It is suggest that hypervisor has to be disabled to get 64bit guests to run.

For recommendations about partitions please look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489769/how-much-hard-drive-space-should-i-allocate-to-ubuntu/489772#489772).

Comment: oh wow how do you manage 20 OS'es at once! - Any recommendations on partition sizes?

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/489769/how-much-hard-drive-space-should-i-allocate-to-ubuntu/489772#489772

Comment: If all your questions have been answered please accept the answer so everyone will benefit, also please edit your question to ask specific questions so it is not closed.